# Not everything what appears so is chocolate.

Tags: idiomatic-language

*Not everything what appears so is chocolate.*

I am not sure if the sentence above is OK. Does it make sense to a native speaker?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80474/discussion-on-question-by-bart-leby-not-everything-what-appears-so-is-chocolate).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am a native speaker of American English.  I can figure out what the example sentence means, but the sentence does not sound natural to me.

As [dwilli](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/74475) pointed out,

> Not everything that appears to be chocolate is chocolate.

is a more natural way of expressing the thought.  Another option is:

> Not everything that looks like chocolate is chocolate.

The latter option is slightly different from the other two options.  "Looks like" implies "has a visual resemblance" more strongly than "appears to be".  "Appears to be" can also refer to other senses, such as smell, hearing, or touch.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/80495/discussion-between-jasper-and-dwilli).

Answer (score 1):

To summarize the discussion on this question, the answer is yes, the sentence makes sense to a native speaker.

The way we understand it is that the word 'what' is a colloquial substitution for 'that'. A much simpler way to understand the meaning of the sentence might be.

> Not everything that appears to be chocolate is chocolate.

It might have been intended as a play on a more common idiomatic saying

> Not all that glitters is gold.

The usage of 'what' in the example would be heard particularly from speakers of cockney English, which is a dialect from London. In movies and popular understanding pirates from the 18th century often are depicted using the the same construction, so it has become a stereotypical idea of how pirates talked.

Comment: Good point. I thought that was a complicated construction for an English learner. I've changed my answer to clarify my intent with that example.